# Powershell - how do I add multiple objects to a property on a custom object?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a project to document a bunch of SSIS packages.  Since the packages are stored in XML it's pretty easy to import the package as XML and I can get to the information I want.

What I think I want to do is capture key information in objects with my own defined properties so at the end I can export the object in a format of my choosing.

I'm trying to get my head around properties of objects and how I would assign multiple objects to a property.

So for instance I create an object $Package that represents the SSIS package.
That package would have some top level properties for instance Name, Path, and Type all stored as strings.  But then there are 5 ConnectionManagers in the package so I want to assign 5 objects representing the ConnectionManagers to $Package.  Now one of the connection managers has 2 expressions so I want to reference 2 objects for the expression property under the ConnectionManager Property.

How do I add a collection of objects as a property of an existing custom object and do I have to add them all at once or can I add to that collection?

Comment: Can you provide some code to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$p = [PSCustomObject] @{
  Name = "packageName"
  Path = "packagePath"
  Type = "packageType"
  ConnectionManagers = @()
 }

$p.ConnectionManagers += [PSCustomObject] @{
  Name = "managerName"    
  Connection = "connectionString"
 }
```

sets up a package with an empty connection manager list, then adds a connection manager object to it.

If you already have a list of connection managers in a variable, replace the [PSCustomObject] in that last assignment with the variable containing the list you want to add

Comment: Thanks I think that makes sense.  Say I had already created $p as a custom object as you have above and wanted to add a new array called "variables" can I do that or do I need to do it at the time of defining the object?

Comment: Mike's answer below is correct, and what I was about to add before I saw that!

Comment: thanks I've accepted your answer as it answered my initial question and upvoted Mikes response.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to Bee_Riii's comment, you do not have to include all properties while defining an object. You can add a new array using [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member).

```
Add-Member -InputObject $p -NotePropertyName myVariables -NotePropertyValue @(1,2,3)
```

You might also choose to use an existing value.

```
$existingValue = @(1,2,3)
   
Add-Member -InputObject $p -NotePropertyName myVariables -NotePropertyValue $existingValue
```

Here I use the variable name `myVariables` as a precaution. Generic names like `name` and `variable` often collide with existing properties. I formed the habit of prepending 'my' to these names to avoid collisions.

You might find these resources useful:

- [ImportExcel | PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel)
- [PowerShell: Creating Custom Objects | TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx)